# How can I easily update the Log Messages view for a branch with new remote commits?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Have the Log Messages view open on my repo on a branch that tracks a remote repo. I know there have been new commits to this branch on the remote repo. I want to update the log view to see these new commits but I'm struggling to work out how to easily do this.

Currently what I do is:

1. Open a File Explorer window.
2. Manually locate the repo on my drive.
3. Right click the repo and from the TortoiseGit context menu select 'Fetch'.
4. Wait for the 'Fetch' dialog to appear, check the correct branch is selected and click 'Ok'.
5. Switch back to the Log Messages view.
6. Click 'Refresh'
7. Select the branch indicator at the top left of the Log Messages view to open the 'Browse References' dialog.
8. In the 'Browse References' dialog select the remote branch my current branch is tracking.
9. Click 'Ok' to close the 'Browse References' dialog.

Now I can see the new commits on the remote branch.

I'd ideally like to see these merged into my local branch without changing my current changeset to the latest one, as I may have local conflicting changes outstanding that I want to think about how to deal with, but I don't see any way to do this. I believe that the only way to copy the new changesets to my working branch is to merge or rebase both of which will either incorporate the changes into my working copy or fail if there's a conflict, instead of simply leaving my working copy alone and displaying the new changesets.

Q1. Is there an easier way to update the Log Messages view to pick up new commits on remote branches?

Q2. Is there some way to apply those new commits to my tracking branch without affecting my working copy?

Answer (score 0):

*(if you have access to terminal* in your context)*

For the fetch part, I'd let a terminal window in the background, pointing at your repo root.

Switch to the terminal, use <kbd>↑</kbd> (up) key to make your previous `git fetch` (which by default fetches all branches from main remote) pop back up, execute, switch back. A few seconds and you just have to refresh your Log Messages window.

Not that it would entirely solve your problem, since the refresh itself is handled in TortoiseGit, but it's worth considering I guess.

* *(since use of TortoiseGit and CLI mix together very well)*